# Size still the same after removing groups

Tags: groups

I am very new to blender and have a model (an .obj file) where I want to remove some groups. Removing the groups are no problem, but when I then import the new file into the program where I'm using the model, with the groups removed, the resulting bounding box is still the same as when the groups were there (the groups are at "the end" of the model, so the size should be smaller).

It's like if the groups are still there, taking up space. 
I have removed the groups by clicking on them in the scene and clicking "Delete". In the resulting .obj file I can find only the two groups that are still there. But for some reason the bounding box volume is the same as when the groups were there. Just to be clear, the bounding box is wrong in the other program I'm using. I can't find the bounding box in blender.

I have also moved the pivot point by following these instructions, and setting the pivot point to the center of the model (I think), by doing Tools -> Transform -> Set origin -> Set origin to center of mass (surface)

I have received these instructions from someone who has removed groups before, but I can't find what the last step means.

1. remove groups
2. move pivot
3. apply all transformations and rotations

Comment: From your description alone this is very hard to diagnose. COuld you edit your question and provide some screenshots of your model before and after. Perhaps even [share your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Applying scale  (Control A/Scale) means this:  your model takes up the same space but doesn't consider itself to be, for example, 200% (or just 2) longer on the X axis - it is reset to being just 100% (or just 1) on all its axes.  Applying rotation (Alt A/Rotation) gives you an object, still oriented the same way, but considering itself to be 0 degrees on each axis. That'll give it a new local X, Y and Z axis, if it has been rotated. Applying Location (Alt A/Location) sends the origin of the object to 0,0,0 on the grid but leaves the geometry where it was.

Answer (score 0):

One way in which you could be left with a bounding box larger than the remaining geometry would be if you deleted the objects while in Edit Mode. Then you would be left with objects with no geometry, but the objects would have their location, scale and rotation information still there.  If this is the case you would need to go to the Outliner to find the mesh-less objects and select them there and then Delete. If your deleted groups had parents, you'd need to open out the items in the Outliner in order to find them.